# Is a RSA private key leak possible if I both sign and decrypt?

Tags: rsa, public-key

Is it possible to leak private key data if attacker control signing request ?

Everyone know $N$ and $E$ because they are public.

My server is designed to decrypt incoming request which is encrypted with public key.

Make sign and for decrypted data which have SHA-2 return back RSA sign for that data.

Is it possible that an attacker can learn my private key?

I am testing this in my local workshop for education purposes.

I am using PKCS#1 public key encrypted message for incoming request;
data is decrypted by my private key and its have SHA-2 so I just sign & return back signed data to client.

Example in Python:

Message & key pair generation:

```
message = struct.pack('>IIII', 0, 0, 0, 1)
(pub, priv) = rsa.newkeys(512) //only for example, I know no one uses 512 bit
```

Incoming request:

```
encrypted = pkcs1.encrypt(message, pub)
```

Server operations:

```
decrypted = pkcs1.decrypt(encrypted, priv)
signature = pkcs1.sign(decrypted, priv, 'SHA-256')
```

and return back answer.

Comment: Are side-channel attack (timing, power analysis..) left aside? Can it be assumed the private key $(N,D)$ is only used to compute the function $X\mapsto X^D\bmod N$? If yes to both: there's no known way the (or a working) private key can leak. But perhaps you are also interested in the server being abused to decipher or sign, there might be attacks allowing that. Independently: please clarify. Use "signature" when it's meant a piece of data, and "sign" for the action of making a signature. What's hashed with SHA2? Exactly how is the result used? Do encryption and signing use padding?

Comment: i have updated my question and added sample too.

Comment: There remains a lot of room for improvement of form: _"make sign and for decrypted data which have SHA2 return back rsa sign for that data"_ -> _sign the decrypted data with padding using SHA2 and return the corresponding signature_; code [formatting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks), perhaps [Mathjax](https://crypto.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1070/555). And it's missing the essential: are side-channel attack (timing, power analysis..) on the Python crypto libraries considered as valid attacks? These can "leak private key data".

Answer (score 1):

It appears from the example that encryption and signature use some padding modes in [PKCS#1](https://pkcs1.grieu.fr/); likely [RSAES-PKCS1-v1_5](https://pkcs1.grieu.fr/#page=23) for encryption and [RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5](https://pkcs1.grieu.fr/#page=31) with SHA-256 for signature.

> Is it possible to leak private key data?

As far as we know, **no**, the fact that it's deciphered a message and signed it with the same key can not *leak private key data*. That's independently of the exact padding schemes used for encryption and signature: we just know no way that any use of an RSA private key $(n,d)$ limited to computing $x\mapsto x^d\bmod n$ in a black box free of side channels can *leak private key data*.

Among similar things that could happen:

- The implementation could leak the private key by a side channel; such as a down-to-earth trojan program running on the platform, or [Differential Power Analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_analysis). There are many other side-channels to fear.
- The implementation of RSAES-PKCS1-v1_5 decryption might be among the [many that are vulnerable to some variant of Bleichenbacher attack](https://eprint.iacr.org/2018/1173.pdf). That could allow turning the server into an oracle that allows (with enough queries) computation of the function $x\mapsto x^d\bmod n$ for arbitrary $x$, giving a (very slow) equivalent to knowing the private key to an attacker that can communicate with the server.

It's not academically correct to use the same public/private key pair for encryption and signature, but with the four encryption and signature modes in [PKCS#1](https://pkcs1.grieu.fr/) it does not enable any known attack. The weakest apparent links in the security chain are

- The very functionality of the server: it allows to obtain the signature of anything that fits the size limitation for encryption (117 bytes).
- The 512-bit modulus, which can be factored (that was already possible in the 20th century).
- The use of RSAES-PKCS1-v1_5 decryption on unauthenticated ciphertext from the open.